When discussing age in Greek, is use of the aorist tense more indicative of when one turned a certain age rather than them just simply being that age?
The Greek text for Luke 2:42 reads: Καὶ ὅτε ἐγένετο ἐτῶν δώδεκα, ἀναβαινόντων αὐτῶν κατὰ τὸ ἔθος τῆς ἑορτῆς
The English translation (KJV) of Luke 2:42 reads: And when he was twelve years old, they went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the feast
Here "was" is a translation of the Greek word "ἐγένετο." In the Greek, "ἐγένετο" is in the aorist tense. Is it true that when discussing age, the use of the aorist tense for "was" suggests the time when someone turned/became a certain age? Furthermore, is it true that if looking to communicate one simply being a certain age (rather than the actual point in time when they turned that age), a verb in the imperfect tense would be used for "was?" Thanks for the help!

The aorist tense is often used to indicate a completed action or event, typically viewed as a whole or as a point in time. It does not necessarily indicate an ongoing or habitual action.
In the given context (Luke 2:42), by the use of the aorist tense, we understand that the event or moment when Jesus has (probably recently) reached or turned the 12-years of age , that is, (not long) past the 12th birthday.
Compare to Luke 3:23:

Καὶ αὐτὸς ἦν Ἰησοῦς ἀρχόμενος ὡσεὶ ἐτῶν τριάκοντα, Ὢν υἱός, ὡς ἐνομίζετο, Ἰωσὴφ, τοῦ Ἠλὶ


Jesus was about thirty years old when he began his public ministry . . .

